# Issues with MsBuild, SpecificVersion, and VSTS

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

The scenario is as follows:

We have a set of common .net libraries:

```
CommonLib.Main
CommonLib.Specialized
```

We have a CI build that builds both of these libraries, and places them into our NuGet repo. Both are available as individual NuGet packages - a user may want to load just Main, or they can pull the Specialized package, which will include Main.

Specialized references Main as a Nuget package.

I'm currently making some upgrades to these packages.

First, I upgraded Main. I updated the version of `Main` in `AssemblyInfo` from **1.1.0.** to **2.0.0.**

MsBuild will include the build number in the "*" location.

The CI Build ran, and a version of Main called "`CommonLib.Main, version=2.0.0.345`" was published to our NuGet repo. On the Nuget repo, the version is listed as "2.0.0", as I would expect.

Next, I upgraded `CommonLib.Specialized`, and I updated the NuGet reference to `CommonLib.Main, version=2.0.0.`

I checked in these changes, and the CI build ran again.

So now, the CI build has create a new version of Main, with version **2.0.0.346**, and placed it on the NuGet repo.

Here's the problem:

Now, when we run our CI build again, the build of `CommonLib.Specialized` fails, because in the .csproj, it looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="CommonLib.Main, Version=2.0.0.345, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\CommonLiib.Main-2.0.0\lib\net461\CommonLib.Main</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

But, in packages.config, it has

```
<package id="CommonLib.Main" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Which pulls down `CommonLib.Main`, Version=2.0.0.**346**.

Our build fails here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CommonLib.Main, Version=2.0.0.345, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. 
For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
Considered "..\packages\CommonLib.Main-2.0.0\lib\net461\CommonLib.Main.dll",
but its name "CommonLib.Main, Version=2.0.0.**346**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
didn't match the expected name "CommonLib.Main, Version=2.0.0.**345**, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
```

I think I could fix this by setting `SpecificVersion` to `false` in the project, but that seems rather crude. Is there a better way to resolve this issue? I feel like I shouldn't have to refresh the NuGet references after every build.

Comment: Why do you include the build number in the assembly version if it isn't part of the nuget package version anyway?

Comment: @SouthShoreAK did you ever get a solution to this